# create drupal 7 webform programmatically?

Tags: 7, webforms

I have already created a webform and I need to fill it programatically.

how can I create webform ? Can i create it like node creation:

```
$node = new stdClass()
$node->type = 'webform'
$node->webform['components'][1]['value'] =  'sss'
```

Answer (score 7):

See code below:

```
function _add_webform_components($node) {
  $components = array(
    0 => array(
      'name' => 'First name',
      'form_key' => 'first_name',
      'type' => 'textfield',
      'mandatory' => 1,
      'weight' => 1,
      'pid' => 0
    ),
    1 => array(
      'name' => 'Name',
      'form_key' => 'name',
      'type' => 'textfield',
      'mandatory' => 1,
      'weight' => 2,
      'pid' => 0
    ),
    ... and so on

  );

  webform_ensure_record($node);
  foreach($components as $component) {
    $component['nid'] = $node->nid;
    $component['extra']['title_display'] = 'inline';
    $node->webform['components'][] = $component;
    webform_component_insert($component);
  }
  $email = array(
    'nid' => $node->nid,
    'email' => 'name@example.ch',
    'subject' => 'default',
    'from_name' => 'default',
    'from_address' => 'default',
    'template' => 'default',
    'excluded_components' => array(),
  );
  webform_email_insert($email);
}
```

Comment: thax very much mr.lenni, my question now is how i can migrate data was interred in drupal 6 webform form to drupal 7 webform? i can access the drupal 6 database and get all the data, but my problem is i cant add the old data to drupal 7 webform and submit it programatically? i hope that my question is clear!

Comment: @genaro, if this is your requirement, edit the question accordingly.

Comment: This is working splendidly for me in Drupal 7. Since I am using it within a script that generates new nodes I had to move the call to ``_add_webform_components()`` after ``node_save($node)`` to avoid errors.

Comment: This looks like it will come in very handy for me, is there a specific function that will allow me to change the settings of the webform? ie, redirect, confirmation message etc?

Comment: Getting issue "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'machine_name' cannot be null" and I found one more key need to add in components array
      'machine_name' => $node->title . '__first_name'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier to understand with this example:

```
function hook_node_insert($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'your_content_type') {
    webform_ensure_record($node);
    $components = _my_function_webform_components();
    foreach($components as $component) {
      $component['nid'] = $node->nid;
      $component['extra']['title_display'] = 'inline';
      $node->webform['components'][] = $component;
      webform_component_insert($component);
    }
    $email = array(
      'nid' => $node->nid,
      'email' => 'name@example.ch',
      'subject' => 'default',
      'from_name' => 'default',
      'from_address' => 'default',
      'template' => 'default',
      'excluded_components' => array(),
    );
    webform_email_insert($email);
  }
}

function _my_function_webform_components() {
  $components = array(
    0 => array(
      'name' => 'Name',
      'form_key' => 'name',
      'type' => 'textfield',
      'mandatory' => 1,
      'width' => '40',
      'maxlength' => '75',
      'weight' => 1,
      'pid' => 0
    ),
    1 => array(
      'name' => 'Age',
      'form_key' => 'age',
      'type' => 'number',
      'mandatory' => 1,
      'max' => '99',
      'excludezero' => 1,
      'weight' => 2,
      'pid' => 0
    ),
    ...
  );

  return $components;

}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can make use of [`drupal_form_submit`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7)  I didn't tried it.

Anyway this may can help you.

> This function allows you to supply values for form elements and submit
>   a form for processing.

The idea is to find the `form_id` check for the form fields and

```
// register a new user
$form_state = array();
$form_state['values']['xxx'] = 'yyyyy';
drupal_form_submit('xxx', $form_state);
```

Give a try and please paste the code here if you succeed.