# Create components of webform including an email component by default when a node is created

Tags: webforms, nodes

I want to create webform components by default  when node is created, all component labels/options of dropdown components/email id for email component are derived from the $node variable on save. is there any hooks or api's I can use?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/39791/9566 looks promising..

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to auto-generate a new Webform for each node published?

Comment: yes exactly that's what i'm trying.