# Create webform on node insert?

Tags: 7, webforms

How do you create a webform on a node insert?

I create an event content type and want to automatically add a webform with 3 fields (lastname, firstname, e-mail) on node insert of the event. I do not want the client to add the webform each time he creates an event node. I want a webform per node.

Comment: see my answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39788/create-drupal-7-webform-programmatically/39791#39791

Comment: Why not use the webform itself as an event content type?

Comment: This was the answer i needed.

Answer (score 2):

Under /admin/config/content/webform you can enable your event content type for webforms, and the form will be created as part of the node creation process.

Edit: Misunderstood!

Webforms are one-off forms. If I now understand correctly, you want to re-use a standard form on each event page (only one form created).

To do this, create a webform with the required fields, and while editing the form, go to the webform tab > Form Settings. Under Advanced Settings at the bottom select 'Available as Block'.

You can then use the Block settings to display the form on every Event page as required.